# Am I computing the attributes of my frustum properly?

Tags: c++, opengl, frustum, culling

I have a basic camera class, of which has the following notable functions:

```
    // Get near and far plane dimensions in view space coordinates.
float GetNearWindowWidth()const;
float GetNearWindowHeight()const;
float GetFarWindowWidth()const;
float GetFarWindowHeight()const;

// Set frustum.
void SetLens(float fovY, float aspect, float zn, float zf);
```

Where the params `zn` and `zf` in the `SetLens` function correspond to the near and far clip plane distance, respectively.

`SetLens` basically creates a perspective projection matrix, along with computing both the far and near clip plane's height:

```
void Camera::SetLens(float fovY, float aspect, float zn, float zf)
{
    // cache properties
    mFovY = fovY;
    mAspect = aspect;
    mNearZ = zn;
    mFarZ = zf;

    float tanHalfFovy = tanf( 0.5f * glm::radians( fovY ) );

    mNearWindowHeight = 2.0f * mNearZ * tanHalfFovy;
    mFarWindowHeight  = 2.0f * mFarZ * tanHalfFovy;

    mProj = glm::perspective( fovY, aspect, zn, zf );
}
```

So, `GetFarWindowHeight()` and `GetNearWindowHeight()` naturally return their respective height class member values. Their width counterparts, however, return the respective height value *multiplied* by the view aspect ratio. So, for `GetNearWindowWidth()`:

```
float Camera::GetNearWindowWidth()const
{
    return mAspect * mNearWindowHeight;
}
```

Where `GetFarWindowWidth()` performs the same computation, of course replacing `mNearWindowHeight` with `mFarWindowHeight`.

Now that's all out of the way, something tells me that I'm computing the height and width of the near and far clip planes improperly. In particular, I think what causes this confusion is the fact that I'm specifying the field of view on the y axis in degrees, and then converting it to radians in the tangent function. **Where I *think* this is causing problems is in my frustum culling function, which uses the width/height of the near and far planes to obtain points for the top, right, left and bottom planes as well.**

So, am I correct in that I'm doing this completely wrong? If so, what should I do to fix it?

**Disclaimer**

This code originally stems from a D3D11 book, which I decided to quit reading and move back to OpenGL. In order to make the process less painful, I figured converting some of the original code to be more OpenGL compliant would be nice. So far, it's worked fairly well, with this one minor issue...

**Edit**

I should have originally mentioned a few things:

- This is not my first time with OpenGL; I'm well aware of the transformation processes, as well the as the coordinate system differences between GL and D3D.
- This isn't my entire camera class, although the only other thing which I think *may* be questionable in this context is using my camera's `mOrientation` matrix to compute the look, up, and right direction vectors, via transforming each on a +x, +y, and -z basis, respectively. So, as an example, to compute my look vector I would do: `mOrientation * vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f)`, and then convert that to a `vec3`. The context that I'm referring to here involves how these basis vectors would be used in conjunction with culling the frustum.

Comment: Surely this cannot be your entire camera class. You also have to multiply the projection matrix by a model/view matrix, and this is the source of a lot of problems when porting from DX to GL. Direct3D uses row-major matrices so the canonical form is `Model * View * Projection`, GL uses column-major so its canonical form is `Projection * View * Model`. Likewise, this applies to the order of Scale, Rotate and Translate - they are reversed between the two APIs.

Comment: @AndonM.Coleman, sorry for the ambiguity - I updated my question accordingly with some distinct clarifications.

Comment: `mNearWindowHeight = 2.0f * mNearZ * tanHalfFovy;` how did you come up with the `2.0f`?

Comment: @Jaa-c, that was actually what the original Camera class had used in the book I snagged the code from :), so I assumed that it was part of the formula for computing the height.

Comment: @blissfreak: I'm sorry, my mistake, it's OK. I seems to me your math is OK.

Comment: @Jaa-c No worries at all, I appreciate you giving it an extra look.

Comment: @blissfreak: Check this [link](http://zach.in.tu-clausthal.de/teaching/cg_literatur/lighthouse3d_view_frustum_culling/), there is all the math you need. What you have here seems OK, I would look for an error elsewhere...

Comment: That is correct, as the name implies `mNearZ * tanHalfFovy` only gives you half of the vertical field-of-view. It basically tells you the maximum distance vertically (+/-) you can see for a point projected some distance forward from the eye. If you want the height from top to bottom of your viewing plane, you need to add both sides together. Here is a [good diagram](http://i.stack.imgur.com/sDZ1z.png) that illustrates this.

Comment: Thanks for the links, peeps. I'll do some digging on Lighthouse and see what else I can come up with.